# Django - PasswordResetView always defaulting to the admin page

Tags: django

I'm using Django's default password reset system, but no matter what I do, I can't get Django to load my custom HTML templates.  It always goes to the [default admin page](https://i.gyazo.com/039cc71b1bf80062bd86d8459c08765e.png).

I have tried using the default folder location and default files names.  Placing 'password_reset_form.html' and 'password_reset_email.html' into the `registration` folder.

`url(r'^password_reset/$', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='reset_password'),`

I have also tried using a custom folder location and custom HTML names.

```
url(r'^password_reset/$', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='change_password/password_reset.html', success_url='../password_reset_done/', email_template_name='change_password/password_reset_email.html'), name='reset_password'),
```

Here is my HTML tag:

```
<p><a href="{% url 'reset_password' %}">Forgot Password?</a></p>
```

Whatever I try Django always loads the default admin page for password reset.  Any tips?

EDIT:

**settings.py**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['bungol/templates', './templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**tree**

```
├───bungol
│   ├───accounts
│   │   ├───migrations
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   ├───templates
│   │   │   ├───accounts
│   │   │   ├───change_password
│   │   │   ├───registration
│   │   │   └───teams
│   │   ├───templatetags
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───accountsext
│   │   └───migrations
│   ├───coresite
│   │   ├───migrations
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   ├───templates
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───databases
│   │   ├───migrations
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   ├───templates
│   │   │   └───databases
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───listings
│   │   ├───migrations
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   ├───templates
│   │   │   └───listings
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───media
│   ├───static
│   │   ├───accounts
│   │   ├───coresite
│   │   ├───databases
│   │   ├───listings
│   │   └───templates
│   ├───templates
│   │   └───static
│   └───__pycache__
├───config
│   └───__pycache__
└───misc (non-coding related stuff)
```

Comment: Can you post the (relevant) parts of your settings file as well as the (relevant pats) of the directory tree?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Added to original post.

Comment: Hi @Valachio, How did you resolve this issue..